# Android Installing Settings.apk

Tags: android, apk

I have a LG F100L running at Android 4.1.2 (JB)
I have deodexed the Settings.apk of the phone and modified it a little
I tried to install it with the following steps:

> 1. Recompiled and Signed the APK using Zipsigner with Platform Keys
>
>    2. Renamed the Setting.apk to Settings.apk.bak and Settings.odex to Settings.odex.bak from /system/app/
>    3. Mounted as system then copy and paste the modified Settings.apk to /system/app
>    4. Set permission of the Settings.apk to rw-r--r--
>    5. Reboot

When i rebooted my phone, it is stuck in a bootloop, i reflashed then rooted my phone then tried again the following method above, still ends the same result.
Am i doing something wrong?

Anyone can help? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Im on Stock ROM BTW.

Comment: yes. you need to see the log if your modified setting is working or not. what if your modified setting contain some bugs?

Comment: I always check the log if compiling was successful or not. It might contain some bugs but still it would run anyway, if a bug/error will occur then that's the time it will crash/force close. What i have edited will not be executed immediately. I have decompiled/compiled and modified some of the other system apps like the Bluetooth.apk, i replaced/installed it without a problem using this method. I'm just having trouble replacing/installing the Settings.apk